# one to one relationship with ef core 5 (use 2 FK)

Tags: entity-framework-core, foreign-keys, one-to-one, ef-core-3.1, ef-core-5.0

I have these 2 Entities. each book can have one or zero BookDetail (1 to 1 Relationship)

```
 public class Book
 {
        public int BookId{ get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string ISBN { get; set; }
        public string Price { get; set; }

        public int BookDetailId { get; set; } /* FK for BookDetail */
        public BookDetail BookDetail{ get; set; }
 }
```

```
 public class BookDetail
 {
        public int BookDetailId{ get; set; }
        public string Weight { get; set; }
        public string NumberOfPages { get; set; }
        public DateTime PublicationDate { get; set; }

        public int BooklId { get; set; } /* FK for Book */
        public Book Book{ get; set; } 
 }
```

I want to have 2 sides foreign key, I just find solutions for just one side foreign key but I want to store FK Id of BookDetail on Book and vice versa in EF Core 5.

- [I know how to configure this relationship with one side FK.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#one-to-one)

Comment: You have already  public int BookId{ get; set; } and  public int BookDetailId{ get; set; } on both classes. What else do you want? I never heard about 2 sides key for my 40 years experience. Could you give an example to us please?

Comment: If you mean a circular foreign key references they are not allowed in any DB. There is a work around but since you can't find this workaround himself it is too early for you to use it.

Comment: 2 FKs define 2 relationships, not one. It's simple - each FK is separate relationship. There is no such thing as "two sides FK" relationship. So, revisit your design/requirements because what are you asking for can't happen.

Comment: @sergey thank you So I need to change this.

Answer (score 1):

To Model the Fact that a Book can have 0 or 1 `BookDetail` you have to make the `FK` on `Book`, pointing to `BookDetail`, `nullable`, check this:

[Fluent API Key Relation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#required-and-optional-relationships)

and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-properties?tabs=data-annotations%2Cwithout-nrt#required-and-optional-properties)

```
 public class Book
 {
    public int BookId{ get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string ISBN { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }

    public int? BookDetailId { get; set; } /* nullable FK to BookDetail */
    public BookDetail BookDetail{ get; set; }
```

}

Is it coherent with reality that a `BookDetail` cannot exist without the book itself, so in this case the `FK` from `BookDetail` to `Book` must not be `nullable`.
I would not "warp" the name of the FK so I can leverage EFCore conventions:

```
 public class BookDetail
 {
    public int BookDetailId{ get; set; }
    public string Weight { get; set; }
    public string NumberOfPages { get; set; }
    public DateTime PublicationDate { get; set; }

    public int BookId { get; set; } /* FK to Book by conventions*/
    public Book Book{ get; set; }
}
```

This would be enough for EFCore conventions to figure out that you have a one to one relation and that `Book` is the Independent memeber of the relation and `BookDetail` is the dependent one: The Independent is always required.

A little extra info: you might want to check owned entites, your BookDetail entity can be seen as a "complex property" of Book, this would mean though that BookDetail could not have an Id by itself.

[Owned Entity Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities)